# Crontab is not working. How do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: centos6, cron

### Fixed by removing `SHELL="/sbin/nologin"` line.

Crons are being called, as Logwatch report indicates. But nothing is actually executing. Neither cURL nor php -q
Here's my crontab -u user -l :

```
root@server [~]# crontab -u user -l
SHELL="/sbin/nologin"
MAILTO=""
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path/?cron
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 240 http://full-path/?cron &>/dev/null
*/4 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://full-path/?cron
*/5 * * * * curl http://full-path/?cron
0 */12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/cron.php
0 */12 * * * php -q /path/to/cron.php
```

Even though they are executed correctly when inserting directly into SSH.

Log:

```
root@server [/var/log]# tail -30 cron
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19460]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/malservertect/malservert --mkpubpaths >> /serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19459]: (cacti) CMD (php /home/cacti/public_html/cacti/poller.php > /serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19457]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19455]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg --lock-file /var/lock/mrtg/mrtg_l --confcache-file /var/lib/mrtg/mrtg.ok)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19458]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19463]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19462]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:20:01 server CROND[19461]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:21:02 server CROND[19741]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path &>/serverv/null)
Jul 19 19:21:02 server CROND[19742]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:21:02 server CROND[19743]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:22:01 server CROND[19826]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:22:01 server CROND[19828]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:22:01 server CROND[19827]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:23:01 server CROND[19890]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:23:01 server CROND[19891]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:24:01 server CROND[19966]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:24:01 server CROND[19965]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:24:01 server CROND[19967]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path &>/serverv/null)
Jul 19 19:24:01 server CROND[19969]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:24:01 server CROND[19968]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20035]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20036]: (cacti) CMD (php /home/cacti/public_html/cacti/poller.php > /serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20038]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20037]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/serverv/null 2>&1)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20040]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:25:01 server CROND[20039]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg --lock-file /var/lock/mrtg/mrtg_l --confcache-file /var/lib/mrtg/mrtg.ok)
Jul 19 19:26:01 server CROND[20193]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl -m 240 -s http://full-path)
Jul 19 19:26:01 server CROND[20194]: (my-user) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/my-user/public_html/cron.php)
Jul 19 19:26:01 server CROND[20195]: (root) CMD ((sync;echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sync) >/serverv/null 2>&1)
```

How do I troubleshoot it? CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Comment: What your logs say?

Comment: Added to the original question. @OndraSniperFlidr